# Struggling with webkit-transition in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I've tried a few variations of using webkit-transition that I've found from googling but I've not been able to get any to work. I have some audio controls that I make appear on a click event, they appear suddenly and jerky so I want to fade them in. The target browser is iOS so I am trying webkit extensions.

This is what I currently have:

```
  <div id = "controls">
    <audio id = "audio" controls></audio>
  </div>


#controls {
    position:absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left:73px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    display:none;
}

#audio {
    opacity:0.0;
}


audio.src = clip;
audio.addEventListener('pause',  onPauseOrStop, false);
audio.addEventListener('ended',  onPauseOrStop, false); 
audio.play();
audioControls.style.display = 'block';
audio.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "opacity 0.4s");
audio.style.opacity = 0.7;
```

The documentation for webkit-transition says it takes effect on a change in the property, so I was assuming changing style.opacity in the last line would kick it off.

The controls appear with an opacity of 0.7 but I want it to fade in and that animation isn't happening.

I also tried this:

```
#audio {
    opacity:0.0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

Also tried

```
audio.style.webkitTransition = "opacity 1.4s";
```

from this posting [How to set CSS3 transition using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742249/how-to-set-css3-transition-using-javascript)

I can't get anything to work, I'm testing on iOS, Safari desktop and Chrome. Same non result on all of them.

## UPDATE:

Following the answers provided the controls now appear in a smooth manner, but fading them out isn't working (they disappear immediately, I've put a long duration in to make sure I can see it happening)

```
if (audioControls.style.display && audioControls.style.display === 'block')  {
    // controls are currently displayed
    audio.removeEventListener('pause',  onPauseOrStop, false);
    audio.removeEventListener('ended',  onPauseOrStop, false); 
    audio.pause();
    audioControls.style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(function () {
        audioControls.style.webkitTransition = "opacity 4.0s";
        audioControls.style.opacity = 0.0;
    }, 0);
}
else {
    // controls are not displayed, display them and play the audio
    audio.src = clip;
    audio.addEventListener('pause',  onPauseOrStop, false);
    audio.addEventListener('ended',  onPauseOrStop, false); 
    audio.play();

    audioControls.style.display = 'block';

    setTimeout(function () {
        audioControls.style.webkitTransition = "opacity 4.0s";
        audioControls.style.opacity = 0.7;
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like the issue you're having is that the opacity is being set to `0.7` as soon as the page loads, even though you have it set to `0.0` in the CSS and you're setting the opacity to something else after you set the transition.

This problem is related to how web browsers work. They are single-threaded and run on an event loop. Things like animations only get processed during a paint event. However, no paint event is happening until *after* your opacity is set to `0.7`. Therefore you need to delay the opacity setting operation until after a paint event gets a chance to process.

The easiest way to accomplish this is to throw it in a `setTimeout` to get it placed back on the end of the event queue:

```
audio.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "opacity 0.4s");
setTimeout(function () {
    audio.style.opacity = 0.7;
}, 0);
```

This probably feels a bit awkward, but it gives the browser a chance to paint the control at `0.0` opacity before going back to paint it at `0.7` (which will get animated because of the CSS transition property.

Comment: Cheers, and thanks for the explanation of the reason due to threading.

Comment: Making the controls fade on appearance works now, but trying to fade them out doesn't work. I've updated my question  with further javascript for the part handling the appearance/disappearance of the audio controls.

Comment: Setting `display: none;` causes your div to disappear before it's animated. You need to set it after a `transitionend` event as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277380/css3-transition-cannot-repeat/12277760#12277760

Comment: @Duopixel is right, you need to delay your `display: none;` until after the animation is done. You can do this by hooking into an animation event, but I'm a fan of the poor man's solution, which is to simply use `setTimeout(function() { /* set display to "none" */ }, 4000)` (where that 4000 is the length of the animation in milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you hit a Webkit bug, I've never seen this happen with any other html elements, so it must be that you're trying to transition before Webkit is done drawing the controls of the `audio` element.

To solve this you can either remove `display: none` from `#controls` (it will be invisible through opacity anyways) or wrap a timeout when you set the transition:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 audio.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "opacity 0.4s");
 audio.style.opacity = 0.7;
}, 0) //0 works for me in Chrome, but you might need to increase it for Mobile Safari
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zyGF7/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Pete pipped you to it by 4 minute so I had to mark his as the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually it's the other way around, but no worries! Pete's answer is great.